# Ionic - How to turn an ion-list into a grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have an ion-list of clickable items that I want to turn into a grid of square items (boxes) and I don't know how. Please help.

Here is my list:

```
<ion-view>

  <ion-content>
     <ion-list >
      <ion-item ng-repeat="letter in letters" href="#/letters/{{letter.number}}" class="letters-list">
        {{letter.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Please how to turn this into square item boxes?

Comment: add class names `<ion-list class="row">` and `<ion-item class="col">`. Let me know if it works

Comment: @Mr_Perfect it works but it puts every thing in a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add classes with respect to the device size. `class="col col-50"` used to show every item size will be 50% of the total width. for more info http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

```
<ion-view>

  <ion-content>
     <ion-list class="row">
      <ion-item class="col col-50" ng-repeat="letter in letters" href="#/letters/{{letter.number}}" class="letters-list">
        {{letter.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

If you are unable to do it with `ion` tags, try to do it with `div` tags.

```
  <ion-content>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="letter in letters" href="#/letters/{{letter.number}}" class="letters-list">
        {{letter.title}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

on of them must work. Of course both.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr_Perfect. I am a little new to it all. I have a list of about 50 items I need like five per row. I added a `col-20` but it still kept everything on a single col. Please how can i have 5 items per row, i.e 5 columns? Thanks

Comment: Can you please show me a demo or example in the editor like fiddle or plunker?

Comment: Thanks @Mr_Perfect. It worked with the `div` s. I just need to style the boxes more now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col <!-- Specify column size and start your loop here -->>
      <ion-item>
        {{letter.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Everything will be put in a single row, but by specifying the col width it will wrap. From there you can style the individual item or its contents.

Hope this gets you a little closer.